# Please explain how does the second line of code works

Tags: python

Please explain the second line of code.

Code:

```
s_counter = collections.Counter(s).most_common()
s_counter = sorted(s_counter, key=lambda x: (x[1] * -1, x[0]))
```

Comment: There's a similar answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62208185/what-does-arr-sortkey-lambda-x-x0-x1-mean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
import collections

s = [2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1]
s_counter = collections.Counter(s).most_common()
```

This gives

```
[(2, 3), (4, 2), (1, 2), (3, 1)]
```

Note that in the result, `(4, 2)` occurs before `(1, 2)`, since 4 occurs before 1 in the array.

Apparently, the author of the code wants to sort the results both by frequency and value. To this end, he defines the sort key as `lambda x: (x[1] * -1, x[0])`. Given tuples of `(value, frequency)`, this will sort by `x[1]` (frequency) first; multiplying by -1 makes it a descending sort. The secondary sorting criterium is the value itself. This will be an ascending sort. Thus, the result is:

```
[(2, 3), (1, 2), (4, 2), (3, 1)]
```