# Python Dictionary to Array

Tags: python, arrays, dictionary

I have the following code in Python converting a dictionary D into a sorted array res

```
res=[]
res =sorted(D.items(),key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0]))
```

What does `x:(-x[1],x[0])` mean?

Comment: `(-x[1],x[0])` is a _tuple literal_ - it creates a tuple consisting of the value of `-1 * x[1]` as its first element and the value of `x[0]` as it's second

Comment: it sorts with priority on last item `-1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62208185/what-does-arr-sortkey-lambda-x-x0-x1-mean

Comment: ^^^ Does this answer your question? [What does arr.sort(key=lambda x: (x\[0\],-x\[1\])) mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62208185/what-does-arr-sortkey-lambda-x-x0-x1-mean)

Answer (score 0):

<sup>(Btw, initiating with *`res=[]`* isn't necessary here.)</sup>

Setting *`key=lambda x:(-x[1],x[0])`* [same as <kbd>**`key=lambda k,v: (-v,k)`**</kbd>] tells the `sorted` function to sort `D.items()` [which is a list of tuples each containing a key-value pair] to first sort by values (in reverse, because of the negative) and then [if there are multiple values that are the same] by keys.

For more details, you might want to read [this article on How a List of Tuples is Sorted](https://learnpython.com/blog/sort-tuples-in-python/#:%7E:text=The%20sorted()%20method%20sorts,and%20the%20third%20with%203.&text=The%20second%20element%20is%20the,by%20the%20sorted()%20function.) and/or documentation on [sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions), [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda) expressions and the [`.items`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items) method.